# Variable set in batch file won't show

Tags: variables, batch-file

When I do this in Notepad, the command prompt doesn't show `ping %ip% -t -l %package%`, but it shows `ping %ip% -t -l` and doesn't show the package variable.

```
@echo off
set data=0
set package = -600

IF %data% == 0 (
    set /a package= %package% + 1600
    @echo ping %ip% -t -l %package%
    )

echo %package%
pause
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try removing the spaces in the set commands around the equal signs.

Comment: You should use `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and ˙!package!˙ instead of `%package%` everywhere within `IF "%data%" == "0" ( ...)` command. [Learn more...](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N"

The `set "var=value"` syntax ensures that any trailing spaces on the batch line are not included in the value assigned to `var`.

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Note therefore the use of `CALL ECHO %%var%%` which displays the changed value of `var`.

So:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /A data=0
set /A package=-600

IF %data% == 0 (
    set /a package=!package!+1600
    echo ping %ip% -t -l !package!
    )

echo %package%
pause
```

Noting: The `setlocal` statement should normally be placed at the start of the code. Your posted code is evidently a snip, since you do not appear to be setting `ip`.

Spaces are irrelevant in a `set /a` but even so, removing them fosters a habit

`Set /a` uses the `run-time` value, not the `parse-time` value of `var` when the syntax `set /a var=var+1` is used within a loop, so `set /a var=var+1` and `set /a var=!var!+1` are equivalent but `set /a var=%var%+1` uses the value of `var` at the time the loop is `parsed`.

Since echoing is set to `off` by the initial statement, the leading `@` on the second `echo` is redundant.